# Store prop as useState

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to achieve sorting function from child, where the props are pass in from parent from an axios call- Should I

1. store prop in child useState
2. pass in parent setState from prop
   for achieve that?

Assume that I do not need parent rerender for sorting, my thinking is 1 could be more favourable - it just that I am not sure storing prop in setState is a common pattern.

First case ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-kilby-c3g4m6?file=/src/Child.js:0-484)) - store prop in child useState

parent jsx

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const taskRefs = useRef([]);
  const [cellContent, setCellContent] = useState([2, 1, 3]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("parent render")
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    //this content is get from axios call
    setCellContent([3, 2, 1]);
  }, []);

  return <Child cellContent={cellContent} />;
}
```

child jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export const Child = ({ cellContent }) => {
  const [sortState, setSortState] = useState(cellContent);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(cellContent);
  }, []);

  const sort = (a) => {
    cellContent?.sort();
    setSortState(cellContent);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={sort}>sort</button>
      <div>{sortState?.map((a) => a)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Second case ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-ganguly-1s8kbx?file=/src/Child.js:0-450))  -pass in parent setState from prop

parent jsx

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const [cellContent, setCellContent] = useState([2, 1, 3]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("parent render");
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    //this content is get from axios call
    setCellContent([3, 2, 1]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Child cellContent={[...cellContent]} setCellContent={setCellContent} />
  );
}
```

Child jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export const Child = ({ cellContent, setCellContent }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(setCellContent);
  }, []);

  const sort = (a) => {
    cellContent?.sort();  
    setCellContent(cellContent);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={sort}>sort</button>
      <div>{cellContent?.map((a) => a)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between the two.

The first one you only pass the state and function to change the parent state from child, this WILL re render the parent component when you sort it.

The second one you pass the value and create your own state in child. this will NOT cause re render the parent conponent when the child state changes (sort).

However, if the parent component re render, the child state will get updated to the parent state too! this can be dangerous if you dont want to lose your local state when parent re render

I think ultimately it depends on your use case, if you want to update the parent then use the first method where you pass the function to change state to child.

But if you want to do it for optimization purpose, and you just want to copy the state to the child, you may prefer the second method, however keep in mind the state is not connected to the parent anymore in this case, but parent will override your child state whenever it rerenders